# Bash Unix: How can i pause a process without using sleep command

Tags: bash, unix, sleep

Hi im trying to pause the execution of a process so that a user cannot make multiple entries until 5 seconds have elapsed. I tried using sleep but sleep simply stops and then executes all the inputs the user ran while the process was asleep, i dont want there to be any input read from when the program was sleeping.

example of what i want:  a chat bot
input 1: hi
output: "reply from program"
input 2 (before 5 seconds is up): "whats new"
-no output-
input 3 (5 seconds have passed): "how are you"
output: im fine.

example of what sleep command does:
input 1. "hi"
output "hey"
input 2 (before 5 seconds): "whats new"
-no output- waits
input 3: "how are you"
output: "not much is new"
output: "im fine"

Comment: Use a while loop and count the time.

Comment: This is not an easy task: it is not your program that is the issue here, but the way the environment works: it buffers the input until it is accepted again by your program. You could try to detach temporary from the input, but probably the easiest simply is to actually read and dump all input for 5 seconds.

Comment: @LucasPiske You want to read the question again.

Comment: Seems like there should be something you can do at the terminal level with `stty`, but I haven't found anything yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can read and throw away the user's input after the 5 seconds is up

```
# 1. 
read -p "prompt 1: " first_thing

sleep 4

# this reads and ignores whatever the user has typed during the sleep
while read -t 1 _garbage; do :; done

# 2.
read -p "prompt 2: " next_thing
```

`read`s `-t 1` option is a timeout of one second if there's nothing to read.

Testing

1. with input

   ```
   $ read -p "prompt 1: " first_thing; sleep 4; while read -t 1 _garbage; do :;done ; read -p "prompt 2: " next_thing
   prompt 1: foo
   bar
   baz
   prompt 2: qux
   $ echo $first_thing $next_thing 
   foo qux
   ```
2. no "extra" input before the 2nd read -- process does not "hang" awaiting input

   ```
   $ read -p "prompt 1: " first_thing; sleep 4; while read -t 1 _garbage; do :;done ; read -p "prompt 2: " next_thing
   prompt 1: hello
   prompt 2: world
   $ echo $first_thing $next_thing 
   hello world
   ```

Answer (score 1):

This is by no means easy, and you need to be more specific about how you expect the script to respond to keyboard input.

There is no way to "lock" the keyboard; the user can continue punching keys as they see fit. If you are content for the keys to be echoed, but you want the input to be ignored, you could do something like the following:

```
# Beware! Read the entire answer; don't just use this command
timeout 5 bash -c 'while :;do read -s -d ""; done'
```

The `timeout` utility runs a command, killing it when the specified number of seconds have elapsed; the specified number may be a decimal fraction. The loop around the `read` command is necessary because the `read` would other terminate as soon as the Enter key is pressed; `while :; do` is a standard idiom for "loop forever".

The `timeout` command is part of Gnu coreutils. If you don't have it, perhaps because you are using a BSD derivative, you can probably find alternatives. There is a FreeBSD command, probably available on other BSDs including Mac OS X, called `timelimit`; I believe the correct invocation would be to replace `timeout 5` with `timelimit -t 5 -s9`, but I don't have any easy way of testing.

You need to get the `read` command to actually read input immediately, as opposed to waiting until the Enter key is pressed. Otherwise, the typed input will still be available to the next command after the `read` is terminated.

There are several ways to do this. One is to use the `-n 1` flag to cause the `read` to return after each character; another one is to use `-d ""` to set the end of input character to `NUL`, which has the side effect of putting read into character-at-a-time mode.

Also, you will probably want to suppress echo of the keys pressed while you are in the read loop. You can do that by adding the `-s` flag to the `read` command, but again that will have the side effect of leaving the terminal in "no echo" mode when the `read` command is interrupted. [Note 1]

Unfortunately, you'll probably find that the terminal settings have been permanently changed, because when `read` is killed by the `timeout` command, it doesn't have a chance to restore the terminal settings. So you'll end up with a terminal which doesn't echo, doesn't handle backspace and other line-editing commands, and doesn't honor Ctrl-D, amongst other issues.

To avoid this problem, you need to save and restore the terminal settings. You can do that with the `stty` command, as follows:

```
# Save the terminal settings
saved=$(stty -g)
# Ignore input for 5 seconds, suppressing echo  
timeout 5 bash -c 'while :;do read -s -d ""; done'
# Restore the terminal settings
stty "$saved"
```

---

1. If you don't suppress echo, you'll find that your input prompt may appear on the same line as the ignored input. You could avoid that by outputting a "carriage return / erase to end of line" control sequence before the prompt:

   ```
   tput cr; tput el; read -p "Give me some input: "
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @glenn is a good answer!
Maybe you don't know in front how long you are going to sleep (you are calling
some other functions). 
When you just want to flush the input queue, you can try a similar approach:

```
echo "What is your name?"
read name
echo "Please be quiet for 5 seconds"
sleep 5

smalltime=0.000001
read -t ${smalltime} -s garbage
while [ -n "${garbage}" ]; do
   echo "Flushing $garbage"
   read -t ${smalltime} -s garbage
done

echo "Hello ${name}, please say something else"
read y
echo "You said $y"
```